# How to force Invoke-Sqlcmd consider SQLCMDUSER/SQLCMDPASSWORD env vars?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd)

```
This cmdlet also accepts the SQLCMD scripting variables, such as SQLCMDUSER. By default, this cmdlet does not set SQLCMD scripting variables.
```

But whenever I'm trying to set up credentials within env vars, the cmdlet does not consider them

The script below works fine

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE master;" -ServerInstance "." -Username "user" -Password "password"
```

This script does not work

```
$env:SQLCMDUSER="user"
$env:SQLCMDPASSWORD="password"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE master;" -ServerInstance "."
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding what it means by sqlcmd scripting variables; it *doesn't* mean Powershell environment variables.. See [sqlcmd - Use with Scripting Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu: except that `sqlcmd` does use values from the environment to supply values for scripting variables, as documented on the very page you link. `Invoke-Sqlcmd` does not seem to, which is fair enough, but also makes the remark of the documentation that you can use variables "such as `SQLCMDUSER`" very misleading, since the `sqlcmd` docs explicitly demonstrate setting `SQLCMDUSER` through the environment -- and in fact it makes no sense to set it anywhere else, since you could just use the `-U` option if you wanted to supply it directly.

Comment: `Invoke-Sqlcmd` exhibits even more weirdness: `Invoke-Sqlcmd -Variable "SQLCMDUSER=x"` is permitted and sets a variable *persistently* -- that is, after this you can do ``Invoke-Sqlcmd -Server . -Query "SELECT '`$(SQLCMDUSER)'`` and it'll give you back the value. But (again to keep up with the confusing docs) this variable is *not* used to specify the user, as it would be with `sqlcmd`; it's treated as a regular variable. And no, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` does not use *PowerShell* variables either, and no, `$SQLCMDUSER` is not the same thing. The more I learn about `Invoke-Sqlcmd` the less I like it.

Comment: The [sqlcmd Utility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) does say, _Users are not prompted if the SQLCMDUSER or SQLCMDPASSWORD environment variables have been set. If neither options nor environment variables are provided, Windows Authentication mode is used to sign in._ Perhaps try `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("SQLCMDUSER", "user")` and `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("SQLCMDPASSWORD", "password")` to see if you get a different result. It shouldn't be any different, but you never know... maybe `Invoke-SqlCmd` is passing `-X`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("SQLCMDUSER", "user")` does in fact work, if not overridden by `-Variable`, good catch! That is -- it works in that it will be used as the value for `SQLCMDUSER` if you expand it; it will not actually be used as the user name (not even if `SQLCMDPASSWORD` is also set). One step forward... Note that, despite its deceptive name, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` *does not invoke `sqlcmd`*. It's just a cmdlet that attempts to imitate the behavior of `sqlcmd`, with all sorts of weird differences.